# How to make a smooth transition between pages that have a dark/light mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I designed a web with a light/dark mode option, and when I make a transition to another page it flashes because the body has a set background-color.

Imagine you start at light color, and you change it to dark, and then go to the next web, well, you've got a problem. Even if you made the page save on LocalStorage the color of the theme, it will flash when you make the transition, because the javascript must be executed when everything loads, if you don't do this it will crash and send an error saying the body element doesn't exist.

I discovered that the reason behind the flashing is that it sets the color that the CSS tells it to use (and even if you dont set any background-color it will use white as default so the problem doesn't change), and then it executes the javascript when everything loads. To fix this I just used the javascript to modify the CSS without using window.onLoad, that way I modify the css, and it changes instantly and no flashing happens.

Edit: typo

Edit2: If you think that you can set the background-color in the CSS, well that's what you would normally do and it shouldn't give any problems, but when you make a web with a light/dark mode, you can't do this, because it will flash. If you set the background-color to #424242, it will flash with #424242 color when you are using light mode (F2F2F2 background-color set in javascript), and when you set the background color to #F2F2F2 it will flash when you are using dark mode (#424242 background-color set in javascript). Thats why I needed it to be dinamically changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code.

```
var myStyle = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(myStyle);
var mySheet = myStyle.sheet;
//You can use a conditional "if" if you want to check the
//localStorage and change the theme dynamically
mySheet.insertRule("body{background-color:#424242}", 0);
```

PS: Shoutout to this guy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChwQ95HQbnI